# QR Barcode image back to text

Tags: php, qr-code

I've converted `hello world` to QR Barcode image but my question is about getting the text back.

[image]

I mean if I sent that image to my friend, then is there any way that my friend get it back to text without using mobile reader/barcode reader machine .etc. so is there any PHP function can do this?!

If not then is there any idea I can convert text to encoded image then with PHP function whatever! I can get it back to text?!

Comment: You could write the text below.

Comment: @sshow my question is about convert text to image and getting it back to text.

Comment: Why would you send text to someone in the form of an image if you don't want them to have to decode an image? just send the text.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There are several web based QR decoders.  Your friend can just upload the image and the service will tell her what the code says.

One of the most popular is ZXing - http://zxing.org/w/decode.jspx

There are also others at

http://www.onlinebarcodereader.com/

http://www.patrick-wied.at/static/qrgen/

Answer (score 7):

I use the [ZBar bar code reader](http://zbar.sourceforge.net/) on linux (there's also a Windows and an iPhone binary), which can scan them using any supported video in device or a number of file formats (e.g., directly from PDF). It's also useful if you want to script the QR code processing.

E.g.,

```
$ zbarimg https://i.stack.imgur.com/pQV0s.png  
QR-Code:hello world
```